# $\{y(n)\} \in l_1$ if $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} x(n) y(n)$ converges for all $x(n) \in c_0$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\{y(n)\}$ a sequence of reals (or complex) numbers such that $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} x(n) y(n)$ converges for all $\{x(n)\} \in c_0$ (it means $\lim_{n \to \infty} x(n) = 0$). Then I have to show that $\{y(n)\} \in l_1$, it means $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} |y(n)| < \infty$.

Should I have to replace $x(n)$ by a concrete sequence to show it? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_n\overline{y_n}$ for every $(x_n)\in c_0$ implies $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|y_n|<\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1936540/convergence-of-sum-n-1-inftyx-n-overliney-n-for-every-x-n-in-c-0-i)

Comment: In the case of the field $\mathbb{C}$ of course yes